Spring Boot & Spring Data JPA - Need to use @Transient annotation, but its preventing data.sql from populating the database during initialization
I have the following scenario: There are 3 Entities: Cart, CartProduct and Product. I have created the entities using the classes itself, which are having the following relationship with one-another.
enter image description here
The problem is, I don't want any PERSIST operations done on cart product to reflect in Cart.
But for this if I remove the cascade operation (which is the obvious solution), I am facing the below issue:
I have a POST endpoint which takes a Product object and populates the Cart and CartProduct database with the product details.
For this particular endpoint, If I do a save (cartRepo.save()), it's trying to update the product table with the product details from the request, which is not something I want, because the user who is updating the cart is a consumer and only a seller should be updating the product table.
So, I tried to use @Transient annotation for this, but it's now preventing the data.sql from populating the database during initialization for product database via CartProduct table.
Is there any way to get over it??
I tried @Transient annotation and tried to use @Embedded as well. But it doesn't seem to work properly. What is best way to proceed here?
